# Internal Electrophilic Aromatic Reaction in 3-chlorobutylbenzene

Tags: aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

I recently came across the reaction scheme: Aluminum chloride to 3-chlorobutylbenzene.

In Jerry March, reaction scheme is provided for 4-chlorobutylbenzene with $\ce{AlCl3}$ where ring closure occurs resulting in formation of a six membered ring. However, since $\ce{AlCl3}$ is being used:

1. Rearrangement of carbocation is possible as $\ce{AlCl3}$ forms carbocation unlike $\ce{FeCl3}$
2. A secondary carbocation is formed initially

**Question**: If the carbocation rearranges to a primary carbocation (formation of six membered ring over a five membered ring), then the reaction would proceed to give a 6 membered ring. However, if no rearrangement were to take place (as secondary carbocation is more stable in comparison to primary), the product formed would be a methyl substituted five membered ring.

So, would the reaction path be decided by the intermediate stability or by the product stability?

Comment: The carbocation rearrasngement (depending on conditions) occurs primary to secondery, not vise versa.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne while i understand that concept that you're trying to say, my question also lies in the fact that in Jerry March, the primary carbocation wasn't rearranged to a secondary cation

Comment: @shukraditya bose , reaction scheme and page number with edition eoukd help in answering. And circumastance of reaction can be understood.

Comment: Apologies. It's the 4th Edition of Jerry March's Advanced Organic Chemistry, Page Number 547

Answer (score 4):

Intramolecular Friedel-Crafts cyclization (either by acylation or alkylation) is an useful methord for the synthesis of bicyclic or polycyclic aromatic compounds. The cyclization of (4-chlorobutyl)benzene in the question is an exsample of such reaction. This perticular case has been studied (among other cases), and the study of rates of rearrangement versus ring closure is reported in Ref.1. The study indicate that in deed, the rearrangement to 5-membered ring has been occured via secondary carbocation, yet the closure to the 6-membered ring must be faster than closure to the 5 membered ring in the given case (as OP found in Jerry March book):

[image: Cyclization of 4-chlorobutylbenzene]

The abstract states that:

> ...Cyclialkylation rearrangements of both primery and secondery phenylalkyl chlorides were observed. The extent of rearrangement was less than in comparable intramolecular alkylations only in *cases where a six-membered (tetralin) ring was formed directly*. Five-membered (indan) rings were not formed directly from appropriate primery and secondery phenylalkyl chlorides; extensive hydride exchange and intermolecular polyalkylation interverned in reactions of these compounds. Direct cyclization of primary phenyl alkyl chloride (VIII) to tetralin was shown to take presidence over cyclization to an indene, either directly or over secondery intermediate...

So, what would be the answer to OP's question, "would the reaction path be decided by the intermediate stability or by the product stability?"?

The answer is not that simple. It is clear that the rate of cyclization to six-membered ring is much faster than the rare of cyclization to five-membered ring (the product stability) as well as the rate of cyclization to six-membered ring is faster than the rare of hydride transfer. The catalyst to substrate ratio is also playing a role (Ref.1).

For instance, the cyclization of (3-chloropropyl)benzene to indan has been occured in trace amount, but the yield can be increased to 10% with incresing amount of catalyst (Ref.1). Yet, the cyclization of (3-chloropentyl)benzene has been occured to give 1-methyltetralin as major product (not 1-ethylindan) in good yield. However, the appropriate tertialy carbocations (highly stable compared to secondery version) readily cyclized to give corresponding indans or tetralins (Ref.2). Some of these cases, rearrangements (even Wagner–Meerwein rearrangement) occurs to get the appropriate carbocation intermediate to facilitate the cyclization, but never a secondery to primwary carbocation rearrangement. Thus, it can be conclude that you cannot expect tetralin from (3-chlorobutyl)benzene, but 1-methylindan.

I'd recommend read some other references as well to get the mechansm point of view (e.g., Ref.3 & 4).

**References:**

1. Ali Ali Khalaf and Royston M. Roberts, "New Friedel—Crafts Chemistry. XVI. A Reconsideration of Cyclialkylation and Competing Reactions of Certain Phenylalkyl, Benzoylalkyl, and Acetylphenylalkyl Chlorides," *J. Org. Chem.* **1966**, *31(1)*, 89-95 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01339a018).
2. Ali Ali Khalaf and Royston M. Roberts, "New Friedel-Crafts chemistry. XIX. Cyclialkylations of some phenylalkanols," *J. Org. Chem.* **1969**, *34(11)*, 3571–3574 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01263a075).
3. L. R. C. Barclay, B. A. Ginn, and C. E. Milligan, "Friedel-Crafts Rearrangements. II. Rearrangements during cyclialkylation of ε-aryl sunstituted compounds," *Can. J. Chem.* **1964**, *42(3)*, 579–590 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1139/v64-08).
4. L. R. C. Barclay and E. C. Sanford, "Friedel–Crafts rearrangements. III. Deuterium tracer studies of the mechanism of cyclialkylation of phenylalkyl chlorides," *Can. J. Chem.* **1968**, *46(21)*, 3315–3323 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1139/v68-548).